# Roll back JPA transaction for concurrent update/delete of unmodified entity

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, locking, openjpa

I have the following workflow for my JPA entities

1. Begin Transaction
2. Read entities A, B, C and D
3. Create entities E and F
4. Update entities C and D
5. End Transaction

Note that entities C and D are read and also updated. With proper locking, JPA will find that the entities are dirty at the end of the transaction, and take appropriate action (rollback) in case of concurrent update/delete.

However, entities A and B are only read for reference (no writes). At the end of the transaction, they will not be dirty, so even with locking, JPA will allow them to be updated/deleted by concurrent transactions.

**In summary**, I want my transaction to be rolled back if there are any concurrent writes to an entity that is only read, not modified, in my transaction.

Would a Pessimistic Lock on the read entities work? My real use case may have hundreds of such read entities rather than just A and B, so I'm concerned about the performance impact of pessimistically locking so many entities.

What is the most efficient way of achieving this?

---

Note: I'm using OpenJPA as my implementation, but my compile-time dependencies are restricted to `javax.persistence`. I'd prefer to keep it that way, but I'm open to changing it if absolutely required.

Comment: Is  a manual flush of the read only entities an option (regardless of the fact they have not changed)? If so, using optimistic locking with a @Version field should trigger an Optimistic Locking Exception.

Comment: Well if you have concerns about pessimistic locking then it seems a viable alternative. Just a suggestion.

Comment: I guess you would be looking at locking the read-only entities on load by specifying PESSIMISTIC_READ lock. My understanding is then that no other transaction could obtain a WRITE lock until your transaction had committed. Maybe @Vlad Mihalcea can advise bgtter than me. See his article here: http://vladmihalcea.com/2015/01/12/a-beginners-guide-to-java-persistence-locking/

Comment: @AlanHay Thanks for confirming my understanding of pessimistic locks. I'm hoping someone here has faced this issue and come up with an elegant solution :)